# "Ado.Net Entity Data Model" template with VS2010, EF6 and SQLite EF6 provider?

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite, ado.net-entity-data-model

As I got a pitch for future project specifying XP compatibility I'm trying to test combination of VS 2010 (WinXP SP3), .Net 4.0.3 (later WPF for UI), Entity Framework 6 (as I found out it should be compatible with .Net 4) and SQLite (System.Data.SQLite / .EF6).

I installed "EntityFramework" and "System.Data.SQLite EF6" packages from NuGet.
("System.Data.SQLite EF6" in turn installed System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.EF6 and SQLite.Interop.dll)

Now trying to use "Ado.Net Entity Data Model" template, which I guessed from older tutorials would be next step I get to new connection dialog and no SQLite provider is listed there to select.

I checked my App.config and SQLite data providers are listed there. (If correctly I can't tell)
Looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0.3,Profile=Client" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" 
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" 
           type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" 
           invariant="System.Data.SQLite" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" 
           type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

The app (empty console app) compiles without errors and runs (doing of course nothing).

I am pretty green with EF + SQLite so can you please advice ?
Am I completely on a wrong track with something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after another several hours of desperate googling I found a hint in an old tutorial about `Visual Studio Design Time Component(s)`.
Apparently I was missing the Design Time Components and also System.Data.SQLite libs installed in GAC, without which VS2010 wizards don't 'see' the SQLite provider.
So despite reading in numerous official places that Setup install package is **not** a recommended method of getting SQLite libs into the project, it is actually the **only** way of making VS (2010, 12, ?13?) tools work with it.

Istalled one of "**setup** packages" from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki . In my case "Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)".
The Template now offers SQLite as data provider.